# How can I add an css class generated by a javascript method in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

In my ViewModel I have the following method that returns me the css class depending on `pState`:

```
function MyViewModel()
{
    var self = this;

    self.GetClass = function(pState) 
    {
        var lCssClass;

        switch(pState)
        {
            case "warning": 
                lCssClass = 'bg-yellow';
                break;
            case "red":
                lCssClass = 'font-red';
                break;
            default:
                lCssClass = 'font-default';
                break;
        }

        return lCssClass;
    };
}
```

I want to add the class in my view:

```
<span class="list-item" data-bind="attr : { class : $root.GetClass('warning')}">This is a warning.</span>
```

My problem: the existing class `list-item` will be overridden.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8L6v9h7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`css` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) will preserve existing classes. Use it e.g. like this:

```js
function MyViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
  
    self.GetClass = function(pState) 
    {
        var lCssClass;

        switch(pState)
        {
            case "warning": 
                lCssClass = 'bg-yellow';
                break;
            case "red":
                lCssClass = 'font-red';
                break;
            default:
                lCssClass = 'font-default';
                break;
        }

        return lCssClass;
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```css
.list-item:before { content: ' ✓ '; } /* Just to prove it's preserved. */
.bg-yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.font-red { color: red; }
.font-default { }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span class="list-item" data-bind="css: $root.GetClass('warning')">This is a warning.</span>
```

This is a "straight up" answer to your question. Please also check [@Progrindis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914180/419956) and even consider going a few steps further than that in inverting the way your code work.

PS. If you want an even more "straight up" solution, for example for when you're creating a quick mock up and don't care about neatness of the solution, you can also resort to:

```html
<span data-bind="attr: { class: 'list-item ' + $root.GetClass('warning') }">
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to at least use a computed observable ? From my understanding this GetClass would need to be called each time in order to get updated value.. Defeating the purpose of an observable no ?

Comment: Yes, I agree that there are some code smells that probably need to be addressed (in manners you suggest). However, OP hasn't quite posted enough of his/her setup to be able to do a code review c.q. suggest alternatives without resorting to guessing. This is why I answered the question straight up.

Comment: As such I'd wish @Benoît would undelete his answer so I can upvote it :), it's an even more straight-up answer, well-suited for someone "just wanting to get things working" (e.g. when creating a quick mock-up I think such an approach can be warranted).

Answer (score 1):

You use the `css` binding..

[KnockoutJS CSS Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)

For example :

```
<div data-bind="css: { profitWarning: currentProfit() < 0 }">
   Profit Information
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        currentProfit: ko.observable(150000) // Positive value, so initially we don't apply the "profitWarning" class
    };
    viewModel.currentProfit(-50); // Causes the "profitWarning" class to be applied
</script>
```

you can just add the class itself or you can add conditional logic to decide when its applied.

For your example it looks like you can have `lCssClass` as an observable and apply this to your html :

```
var self = this,
classObservable = ko.observable("");

switch(pState)
        {
            case "warning": 
                self.classObservable('bg-yellow');
                break;
            case "red":
                self.classObservable('font-red');
                break;
            default:
                self.classObservable('font-default');
                break;
        }
```

Then in your HTML :

```
<span class="list-item" data-bind="css: classObservable()">This is a warning.</span>
```